# Error restoring Postgres DB

Tags: postgresql

I'm trying to do a `pg_restore` on some SQL files. Here's the command I used when I dumped from the other database:

```
pg_dump -f /home/mctools/public_html/cp/upload/manufacturers.sql \
        -Fc -i -v -O -x -t manufacturers \
        -h localhost -p 5432 -U aztools_tools aztools_dbuser
```

And here is the restore command:

```
pg_restore -d mctools_dbuser -Fc -c -i -O -x  \
           -h localhost -p 5432 -U mctools_user \ 
           /home/mctools/public_html/cp/upload/manufacturers.sql
```

Here is the error I get:

```
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error while PROCESSING TOC:
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] Error from TOC entry 2165; 2606 27769168
                            CONSTRAINT manufacturers_pk aztools_tools
pg_restore: [archiver (db)] could not execute query: ERROR:  cannot drop constraint
                            manufacturers_pk on table manufacturers
                            because other objects depend on it
DETAIL:  constraint products_fk01 on table products depends on index manufacturers_pk
HINT:  Use DROP ... CASCADE to drop the dependent objects too.
Command was: ALTER TABLE ONLY public.manufacturers DROP CONSTRAINT manufacturers_pk;
```

What do I need to do to fix this?

Comment: I tried to reproduce your problem with no success. The first thing I would check is the output auf `pg_dump` by dumping plain SQL instead of using the PostgreSQL custom format. If it looks fine, try to restore dumped database objects with `psql -f plain_dump.sql`.

Comment: Do you really need the `-c` option in `pg_restore`?  Exactly that's why `pg_restore` tries to drop the objects you dumped.

Answer (score 4):

The `-c` option of `pg_restore` [does this](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/app-pgrestore.html):

> Clean (drop) database objects before recreating them.

As you seem to only migrate a single table from here to there, you can safely omit `-c` from your command line.  If you only need the data, you should tell it to `pg_dump` instead, by using the `-a` option.  If your table structure is different as well, then you should prepare an `ALTER TABLE` statement manually to reflect those changes in the target database.  (You could as well use a few tools for the latter, but for only one table the manual solution is usually much faster.)